# How to save program counter address without using J-Type instructions in MIPS architecture

Tags: mips, program-counter

I have to implement jal instruction as pseudo-instruction without using J-Type instructions. I can implement it with jr but I know that jal stores current PC+8 in $ra. How can I implement that? How can I store PC address in ra without J-type?

Comment: Given that there is no instruction to directly access the current value of the PC register, I'm wondering if this is at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    la  $ra, ret    # load return address (pseudo instruction!)
    j   dest        # call the function
    nop             # delay slot
ret:                # return here
    ...

dest:               # destination function
    ...
    jr  $ra
```

Comment: Thanx for answering, but here you use j dest which is a J-Type and I had been asked to do it without any J-Type instruction.

Comment: @Vlad So replace the `j` with an `la` followed by a `jr`.